# MySQL unknown column 'password_last_changed'

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

When creating a user using this command

```
create user 'foo'@localhost';
```

this error is shown

```
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'password_last_changed' in 'mysql.user'
```

Using MySQL server version: 5.7.6 on linux

I tried to add it but I dont know its data-type 
How can I fix this

Answer (score 6):

From the [5.7.6 release notes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.7/en/news-5-7-6.html):

> If you upgrade to this release of MySQL from an earlier version, you
>   must run mysql_upgrade (and restart the server) to incorporate the
>   changes to the mysql database. mysql_upgrade moves Password column
>   values to the authentication_string column and removes the Password
>   column. For nonupgraded installations that have no account_locked
>   column, the server treats all accounts as unlocked, and attempts to
>   lock or unlock and account produce an error.

Although you will find similar issues in every upgrade, so running this tool is a must. `password_last_change` was added in 5.7.4, so you must update the table definitions.

Please note that at the time, upgrades from 5.6 are supported, but not from 5.5 at the moment of writing these lines, so if you have upgraded directly from 5.5 or below you will likely find problems.

Answer (score 0):

Never touch the system tables unless you know exactly what you are doing. Your are using the latest server that has changed a number of things for which MySQL Workbench needs to be adjusted. So, update to the latest version (6.3 RC is available, with GA around the corner).

Comment: how to update to the latest version, is it the same as myql_upgrade?  how do I update it?

Comment: You are actually using MySQL Workbench? A tag indicates you would.